# Eclipse projects doesn't work after moving directory

Tags: java, eclipse

I have got a problem with my eclipse project, I have moved my workspace from another computer and now when I open the workspace I have got plenty of exclamation marks.

for example:
`import java.util` is underlined in red
`List<Double>` as well,
`super()` as well,
and many other things.

That's the big mess I don't know how to fix it?
I have to clean, refresh but nothing more happened.

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Export your project from previous workspace and import it in the new one. Also, check that JDK is the same in both worskpaces.

Answer (score 0):

Probably Java JDK is not configured properly in your new Eclipse setup. Try opening Build Path properties and see if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the jdk configured in java build path is correct.  If it is wrong then the jdk will have a red x mark; if it is so then re-configure the jdk

Answer (score 0):

- Delete imports, and try to re-import them (if you cant see "import" option, you will probably have bad set of JDK path)
- Check your JDS/JRE's settings in Eclipse project build path
- In last case, try to click on project and "refresh" and project - clean

etc., btw as others wrote- never export project manually, there's function for export :)